# HAproxy, nginx and HTTP/2

Tags: nginx, haproxy, http2

I have few servers and for all of them:

1. HAproxy sometimes is giving SSL certs for connection
2. Sometimes nginx is giving SSL certs

I need to set up HTTP/2 connections, where currently all are HTTP/1.1.

HAproxy redirects traffic to many servers with nginx.

How should I configure HAproxy when nginx is serving certs?

What are good practices with the above?